# Google Chrome in Windows 10 reports network speed eight times lower than other browsers

Tags: networking, google-chrome, microsoft-edge, internet-speed

Is there anything that could explain this:

[image]

Here we have:

- The same hardware (Intel NUC 7i5BNH)
- The same network (network cable and router) and the same ISP
- The same operating system (Windows 10 Pro 10.0.19044 Build 19044)
- The same network speed testing tool (fast.com) and the same destination test server
- The same set of applications running in background
- The same timeframe (both tests run one after another, with 30 seconds separation)
- And two different browsers (Google Chrome 101.0.4951.67 and Microsoft Edge 101.0.1210.53)

And we have network speed reported by two browsers that differs nearly eight times.

This is not a separate situation. The same tests were run (and the same results were received) a couple of times for the following next hour.

To make things even more weird (at least to me) very similar tests were performed in the mean time (again with 30 seconds separation between each test) on another PC. The testing framework was exactly the same (again same network, ISP, operating system, timeframe, testing tool, server and the same set of two browsers), but only run on another PC.

And in this case both browsers has reported nearly the same results:

[image]

Is there any reasoning that can explain that a single browser reports a way different results in a repeatable conditions that another browser on the same computer and all other browsers on all other PCs connected to the same network?

Comment: Personally, when using fast.com speedtest, I have found it nearly random at best - I use the google one when you search for speed test (with the space) - ookla's speedtest is now just a horde of advertising.

Comment: Looks pretty clear to me: Somehow, Chrome on this PC is limited to ~30 MBit/s. Notice the latency: It is artificially inflated.

Comment: May be worth creating a new user, logging in and running speed tests on fast.com again. Chrome is king of crappy cache...

Comment: Thank you all for an ultra fast set of ideas. I'll do the tests tomorrow and report. @JohnnyVegas Given the Google history and their approach to market competitors I wouldn't be very surprised if Google One results on non-Google browser (Edge) would be... quite not so accurate! :) But thanks for the idea.

Comment: Nicely controlled experiment! You might also try adding another browser (e.g., Firefox) and running on another OS, e.g., Ubuntu. Both can be done with **no change to your PC** by running from a live USB, https://itsfoss.com/create-live-usb-of-ubuntu-in-windows/ . Ubuntu comes with Firefox, and you can install (albeit temporarily) Google Chrome while booting and using the USB.